# How to make grid refresh on horizontal scroll

Tags: delphi, scroll, grid, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

After hours, I've been unable to find any reference to this issue, here or elsewhere.
The problem shows with Multi-device applications (hence FMX not VCL), both for Android and Windows (I cannot know for iOS).

**The Setup :** 
Place a grid (`TGrid` or `TStringGrid`) on a form. 
Make the grid larger than the form by adding columns, ensuring that horizontal scrolling will be needed.
In the grid options, choose to draw `ColLines`, `RowLines` and `AlternatingRowBackground`.
`RowSelect` can also be True, to highlight an entire row at once.

**The problem :** When scrolling horizontally, the previously hidden part of the grid does not show any `RowLines` or Background (`ColLines` are well drawn), or highlight from `RowSelect`. 
Coloring and drawing is cut regardless of column limits. When resizing the window to fit the grid (on Windows OS), colors and lines are well drawn on the previously hidden columns.

I've tried, both for `OnDrawColumnCell` and `OnHScrollChange` events :

- `StringGrid.Repaint, Self.Invalidate` : no result
- `Application.HandleMessage, Application.ProcessMessages` : slow down
  the app
- `StringGrid.Canvas.Clear(0)` : slow down and mess up the app
- Change between Debug and Release versions : no result
- Change `Grid.Align` to Client, None, Fit, Contents, Scale : no result

Please, does anyone know a way to make a grid display as expected when scrolled horizontally ?

---

Edit 12-Aug-2016 : Delphi 10.1 (Berlin) is not concerned

Comment: what version of Delphi you are using? i have the same issue with Delphi XE7 Update 1 and Delphi XE8.

Comment: i'm using Delphi XE7 update 1. i've edited my post.

Comment: I have added the corresponding tag for you :)

Comment: I tried a lot but I have the same issue. I suggest to have a look here:
[Tms FmxGrid](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsfmxpack.asp?s=fmxgrid#features)

Comment: @whosrdaddy: thanks for tagging and editing

Comment: @Gianluca: thanks for the advice. I've just tested the trial. It's OK for a Windows app. But Android is my target and when trying to compile for Android, an error occurs saying : "`FMX.TMSXUtils` was compiled with a different version of `Androidapi.Helpers.StrToJURI`". I cannot find the version on TMS site or elsewhere. Do you know where to find the version it was compiled with ? So I try to match it in my Delphi config.

Comment: Note: TMS pack for Firemonkey has a lot of demos for Grids. However very few are ready for Android. And those I found will not compile due to previously mentionned "FMX.TMSXUtils was compiled with a different version of Androidapi.Helpers.StrToJURI".

Comment: @FrédéricHebrard  Probably using the compiled dcu demo!
I'm using the registered version with full source code on my XE7 and I can assure you that TMS works very well on Android Platform

Comment: @GianlucaColombo: OK thanks. We don't plan to buy TMS package, yet. We don't need all that power and I cannot prove it solves the problem. Target is Android 4.4 and above. It's not an option to change that. If TMS demos do not compile in our conditions, it's not good. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it. At last.

For the highlighting to spread over the entire row when selecting it (even the hidden part), one have to play with **Styles**.

I didn't go deep inside style editing but here's what to look at :

- With the grid component (`TGrid`, `TStringGrid`) on a form, right-click the grid and choose **Edit Default Style** or **Edit Custom Style** to open a **FireMonkey Style Designer** window (see [DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/FireMonkey_Style_Designer) for details)
- In the **Structure View** go to : `gridstyle > background > content > selection`
- In the **Object Inspector**, the `Align` property for `selection` is `None` by default : *that's why highlighting won't spread over the entire row !*
- Change the value to `Horizontal` and you're done. Other values will not do the trick. (`Contents`, `Client` : the entire grid is highlighted) (`Fit`, `Center` : highlighting is centered on the grid)

Surprisingly, in Delphi 10.1, default configuration is the same but selection correctly spread over the entire row if needed...

Note : `gridstyle` is `TLayout` ; `background` is `TRectangle` ; `content` is `TLayout` ; `selection` is `TRectangle`